# How to get the data of a "value" attribute inside an element in TestCafe?

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm trying to write a test that takes the amount value of a given element, and then manipulates it in the code. The code for the element is something like the following:

```
<input id="amount" type="text" value="16.95">
```

So how can I get the number value that's inside the "value" attribute?

I've tried to call the element like so:

```
const someVal = Selector('#amount').find('value')
```

But that's obviously wrong as it'd just take me to the element and not the data?

Comment: Please take a look at this article: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: console.log(document.getElementById("amount").value);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have this;

```
<input id="amount" type="text" value="16.95">
```

So in JS, get the value by doing this;

```
document.getElementById("amount").value;
```

Basically, whatever you define as `value` means when it loads, that is what will show first. so in your case as you have `value` defined as `16.95` just call the box and you will get the value.

Use this for reference;
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_text_value2

Comment: it already has an ID :) please correct your answer.